# Comparing two hypothetical investment opportunities.

Tags: probability, statistics

I came across a problem comparing two hypothetical investment opportunities. in both cases, you will invest some money and get a daily return on it. However, the return will follow one of these roles:

1. You will get $\$35$ each day.
2. You will have a $36\%$ probability of getting $\$70$ each day, however, if you did not receive it, the probability the next day will increase by $20\%$. and if you receive it, the probability will reset back to $36\%$.
   (for example, if you did not receive money on day $1$, you will have a probability of $56\%$ of getting the $\$70$. And if you did not get any money on days $1$ and $2$, the probability of getting $\$70$ on the third day is $76\%$. and so on)

**I tried to formulate it mathematically and found that the second option is better, On the other hand, I model the problem in Excel and found that both of them are equal.**

my mathematical solution was based on:

First: find the success probability of some sequenced days, and then average the $\$70$ on these days.

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 1}) &= 36\%\\
\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 2}) &= \Bbb{P}(\text{no return at day 1})\cdot (36\% + 20\%) = 35.84\%\\
\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 3}) &= \Bbb{P}(\text{no return at day 1})\cdot\Bbb{P}(\text{no return at day 2}) \cdot (36\% +2 \cdot 20\%)= 21.4016\%\\
\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 4}) &= 6.488\%\\
\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 5}) &= 0.27\%
\end{align*}

Second, find the equivalent daily return after getting the \$70, which is:

- $\$70$ if you get the return on the first day.
- $\$35(70/2)$ if you get the return on the second day.
- $\$23.33(70/3)$ if you get the return on the third day.
- $\$17.5 then \$14$ for the fourth and fifth days.

finally, the total equivalent daily return of the second option is:
$$Eq_r = \sum_{i=1}^5  P(\text{return at day i}) \cdot \frac{70}{i} =43.91 $$

**What option will result in more return over time?**

Notes:

1. The probabilities in the second option will increase by $20$ until it reaches $100\%$, so they are $\{36,56,76,96,100\}$.
2. The investment in both cases will go on forever.

Comment: This is hard to read.  As a general matter, avoid using dollar signs if you have no idea how to format on this site...dollar signs have a special meaning to the rendering system.

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: I correct it. Is better now?

Comment: Somewhat.  The probabilities are still written as a run-on formula which is hard to parse.

Comment: As a general note:  "better" is subjective.  Here, it depends on a utility function.  What, exactly, are you trying to optimize?  If "Expected Value" then you need to specify a time frame.  If you are doing this for one day, the first strategy is clearly better (using this particular Utility function).

Comment: Also, I don't understand how the probabilities increase.  I get $\{36, 56, 76, 96\}$ but what comes next?

Comment: Assuming the interval is infinite. And after 96 it will be 100,

Comment: Well, you should specify that in your post.  It isn't clear from what you wrote.  But, my comment regarding the Expected Value is more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula
$$Eq_r = \sum_{i=1}^5  P(\text{return at day i}) \cdot \frac{70}{i} =43.91 $$

or equivalently
$$
   Eq_r
 =  \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^5  P(\text{return at day i}) \cdot \frac{70}{i} }
     { \sum_{i=1}^5  P(\text{return at day i})  }
 =43.91
 $$

attempts to calculate an average daily return, by multiplying
probability and its return divided by the number of days.
This makes a good sense as average --- average, **over** your five **possibilities** called "return at day i", of the corresponding equivalent daily return.

But you are interested in the average daily return = average, over **days**, of of what return may get on that day. Case "return at day 5" is something that happens on 5 consecutive days, and the weight that this possibility receives in the average should be 5 times higher:    $$
   Eq_r
 =  \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^5  i \, P(\text{return at day i}) \cdot \frac{70}{i} }
     { \sum_{i=1}^5  i \, P(\text{return at day i})  }
 =  \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^5   P(\text{return at day i}) \cdot 70 }
     { \sum_{i=1}^5  i \, P(\text{return at day i})  }
 = 35,14254943
 $$

(Note: I did recalculate the probabilities, while @jro used your rounded probabilities; hence the small difference in the numbers.)

Comment:
in your formula, you calculate the weighted average of daily returns, calculated with weight of each case "return at day i" proportional to the probability that **case** will be the next case which is going to happen.

In the corrected formula, the weighted average of daily returns is calculated with weight of each case "return at day i" proportional to the number of days times the probability that case will be the next case which is going to happen.
In other words, the weight is probability that a randomly selected **day** in the (infinite) sequence of days will be one of days of the case "return at day i".

**BTW** the formula
$$\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 3}) = \Bbb{P}(\text{no return at day 1})\cdot\Bbb{P}(\text{no return at day 2}) \cdot (36\% +2 \cdot 20\%)= 21.4016\%\\$$
contains correct number but needs to be corrected to
$$\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 3}) = (1 - \Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 1}) -\Bbb{P}(\text{return at day 2})  )  \cdot (36\% +2 \cdot 20\%)= 21.4016\%\\$$

Answer (score 1):

The long run average return of the second option is higher, but only very slightly.
To see this (informally), denote $ T $ the number of days needed to win the payoff (i.e. the return happens at day $T$). Then with the probabilities you computed, $ \mathbb E [T] = \sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb P[T = i] ·i \approx 1.992 $.

When running the process for a long time, we repeat many "cycles" in which we wait for the payoff and restart, and each cycle has an expected length of $ \mathbb E[T]$. Since the cycles are independent, after a long time, the observed average length of the cycles will converge to $ \mathbb E[T]$. This means that on average, we will have one payoff every $ \mathbb E [T] $ days, or equivalently $1 / \mathbb E[T] \approx 0.502 > 1/2$ payoffs per day. Since $0.502 · 70 > 35$, we'd prefer the second option when optimising purely for expected return (though the gain seems paltry given the added volatility).

This also means that in a simulation, it might take a while to spot the outperformance of the second option.

---

Regarding your computation: you computed $ E_{q_r} = 70 · \mathbb E  [1/T] $, so effectively the main difference to the calculation above is that I used $ 1/\mathbb E [ T]$ to estimate the number of payoffs per day, while you used $ \mathbb E[1/T]$. By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_form), $\mathbb 1/\mathbb E[T] \leq \mathbb E[1/T]$ so this explains the discrepancy. As to *why*  $\mathbb E[1/T]$ does not work, I don't have a really satisfying explanation, although you can convince yourself in a simpler example (e.g. win with 50% probability, lose with 50%, but win with 100% following a loss) that it gives wrong results.

---

As a final remark, to make the above points really precise, it is helpful to use Markov chains. In this case, the number of days without any gains since the last payoff is such a chain (depicted below), and one can (rigorously) show that it converges to an equilibrium distribution, in which a fraction of $1/\mathbb E [T] $ of time is spent in the state $0$ corresponding to a payoff.

[image: Sample Markov chain]